# NullPointerException occurs after updating the items of a ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm stuck on this issue, and I have no clue on how to proceed.

I have a JavaFX application setup in a MVC scheme. I have my models `Game` and `Achievement` and their respective `Controller` and `View` classes, `GameController`, `AchievementController`, `GameView`, `AchievementView`. I also have a `DAO` for both `Game` and `Achievement`.

Now in my function `refreshData()` in `AchievementController` I get thrown the following trace of errors:

https://pastebin.com/4TWZ6kjw

I don't understand why this occurs.

**Description of steps:**

When opening a game, and switching scenes from `GameView` to `AchievementView` I call the `refreshData()` function in `

`AchievementController.onSwitchView()`

and it functions fine. Then after I add a new achievement through the

`AchievementController.handleAddButton()`

method, it throws the above trace, triggered by [the line](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/controllers/AchievementController.java#L47) in `refreshData()` which says

`view.getGamePicker().setItems(gameList)`.

I don't get why this happens. I checked with the debugger, and `view`, `view.getGamePicker()` and `gameList` are all non null. `gameList` is a list which contains the exact objects that it's supposed to contain, which are non null too.

I know this is not really a minimum reproducable example, but I really don't know how to pinpoint the lines you actually need. I'm completely stumped! If you need the entire project so you can run it locally, please check here: https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo

Links to (I think) relevant classes:

- [MainApplication](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/MainApplication.java)
- [DAO](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/data/DAO.java)
- [AchievementDAO](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/data/AchievementDAO.java)
- [GameDAO](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/data/GameDAO.java)
- [AchievementController](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/controllers/AchievementController.java)
- [GameController](https://github.com/kemmel-dev/TestRepo/blob/master/src/practicumopdracht/controllers/GameController.java)

You can reproduce this behaviour by adding one or more games in the first screen after launching, then opening one of the games you've just added, and trying to add an Achievement to that game.

Comment: If you read the article on how to create a [mcve], it will help you to isolate the problem and create the code needed to include in your question. Please do not link to outside sources for your code.

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate there's a null reference either in an `ObservableList` or being passed to an `ObservableList`. Either you're genuinely putting something null in there, or there's a threading issue. As previously commented, you need to create (probably from scratch) a minimal example that reproduces the problem, and include both the code and stack trace from your minimal example in the question.

Comment: @Zephyr my issue most likely won't occur in a minimal reproducible example. I think I'm misusing the API and overseeing where that's occurring.

Comment: Well, one suggestion. Your `GameDAO.get(int id);` returns `null` if a game isn't found. Presumably you are writing code that is supposed to ensure that doesn't happen; so instead throw an exception from that method if there's no matching id. (Similarly if there are other places where you do this.) Most likely you have a logic error somewhere which results in null references being silently returned from methods where you don't expect them to. But I doubt anyone's going to look through all that code for you.

Comment: @James_D this is why I included a link so you can clone and run my project, and help me pinpoint what's going wrong, so I'm able to provide a minimum reproducible example of what is actually going wrong, instead of just saying 'well in this general area'. I checked with the debugger, and both `gameList` and `observableGameList` are not null and contain the objects they're supposed to contain (which are not null too)

Comment: This forum isn't really for that. If you want that level of support, you'd need to pay a consultant.

Comment: One thing about cloning a project, if we're being smart, we'd still look through your code first. I'm not in the habit of blindly running large amounts of unknown code on my machine :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure why, but the use of `List.copyOf()` in my `DAO`s was causing this issue. Apparently the `setItems()` method of a `ComboBox` OR the `FXCollections.ObservableList()` method   does not play well with receiving a `List.copyOf()` as it's argument.

Replacing it with `Collections.unmodifiableList` or `new ArrayList<>(objects)` worked...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Don't set the `ComboBox#items` property to an `ObservableList` backed by a `List` which does not permit `null` elements.

---

The important part of your stack trace is in the first few frames (or last few frames, depending on how you look at it):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.indexOf(ImmutableCollections.java:166)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.indexOf(ObservableListWrapper.java:124)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.lambda$new$1(ComboBox.java:245)
```

Specifically, this frame:

```
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.indexOf(ImmutableCollections.java:166)
```

This means you're using one of the [unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) added in Java 9/10, and indeed you confirm this in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591792/6395627). The characteristics of these unmodifiable lists include the following:

> **They disallow `null` elements** *[emphasis added]*. Attempts to create them with `null` elements result in `NullPointerException`.

And the documentation of [`List#indexOf(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), which you can see was invoked by looking at the stack trace, states:

> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements ([optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions))

Then, according to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591792/6395627) again, you use [`FXCollections#observableList(List)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList(java.util.List)). That method:

> Constructs an `ObservableList` that **is backed by the specified list** *[emphasis added]*. Mutation operations on the `ObservableList` instance will be reported to observers that have registered on that instance.

This means you've set the items of the `ComboBox` to an `ObservableList` backed by a `List` which does not permit `null` elements. If you look at the stack trace again, you can see the call to `#indexOf(E)` occurs here:

```
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.lambda$new$1(ComboBox.java:245)
```

Here's the source code (JavaFX 13.0.2) of `ComboBox` around that line:

```java
public ComboBox(ObservableList<T> items) {
    getStyleClass().add(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.COMBO_BOX);
    setItems(items);
    setSelectionModel(new ComboBoxSelectionModel<T>(this));

    // listen to the value property input by the user, and if the value is
    // set to something that exists in the items list, we should update the
    // selection model to indicate that this is the selected item
    valueProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
        if (getItems() == null) return;

        SelectionModel<T> sm = getSelectionModel();
        int index = getItems().indexOf(t1); // LINE 245 (NPE THROWN HERE)

    // REST OMITTED FOR BREVITY
}
```

It is perfectly legitimate for the value of a `ComboBox` to be `null`. This can lead to `t1` being `null` and thus line 245 becomes:

```java
int index = getItems().indexOf(null);
```

And your `NullPointerException` is thrown.

The solution is to make sure the `ObservableList` of items permits `null` elements. [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591792/6395627) indicates you've found at least one solution. If you want to continue returning an immutable, nulls-not-allowed list from your DAO, and you don't mind copying the list returned by your DAO into another list, then you can use [`FXCollections#observableArrayList(Collection)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(java.util.Collection)) when setting the items of your `ComboBox` or even just do:

```java
comboBox.getItems().setAll(collectionFromDao);
```